# MySQL finds a match even when given value is not the same

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table called `accounts` and in there information on user accounts are stored. When I wish to fetch information for any specific user I do it by using their account `id` and the query I execute is usualy as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM `accounts` WHERE `id`="1"
```

and it returns the expected result, all information on that specific account.
However, I was curious and for the sake of testing I decided to add some random characters & symbols after the id.

```
SELECT * FROM `accounts` WHERE `id`="1dslkfjsd"
```

**My question is:** Why does MySQL think that `1dslkfjsd` is equals to `1` ?

is it because the column is of type `int` and it strips away anything which is not `int`?

Screenshots:

---

[image]

---

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conversion rules apply when comparing fieds that have different data types.

From [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/type-conversion.html) :

> - If both arguments in a comparison operation are strings, they are compared as strings.
> - If both arguments are integers, they are compared as integers.
> - [...]
> - In all other cases, the arguments are compared as floating-point (real) numbers.

What happens in your use case is that `1dslkfjsd` becomes `1` when converted to a number.

Answer (score 1):

Yes using a string as integer forces a conversion to your integer column type, equivalent to:

```
SELECT CONVERT('1dslkfjsd', SIGNED INTEGER);
```

If the first part of the string is a valid integer it is used as the return value, otherwise you are likely to get a 0.